# How to extract a list of TRUE from matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have been trying to extract all combinations of "TRUE" from a matrix in R.
I have 5x5 matrix "MAT" here

```
     99    70    33    36    93
99  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
70 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
33 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
36 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
93  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

`dput(MAT)` 
structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("99", "70", "33", "36", "93"), c("99", "70", "33", "36", 
    "93")))
```

I would like to list all combinations of T. I also need to remove duplicate combinations since the matrix has symmetric structure.
I want an outcome looking like

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   99   99
[2,]   99   93
[3,]   70   70
[4,]   33   33
[5,]   33   36
[6,]   33   93
[7,]   36   36
[8,]   93   93
```

I tried `apply(MAT,1,function(data)names(which(data==T)))` but the outcome was as below. If I can convert from the below outcome to the ideal outcome above, that also works. Thanks for your support!

```
$99
[1] "99" "93"

$70
[1] "70"

$33
[1] "33" "36" "93"

$36
[1] "33" "36"

$93
[1] "99" "33" "93"
```

Comment: Please share sample data in valid R syntax that is copy/pasteable, not as a screenshot. If your matrix is called `MAT`, then `dput(MAT)` will create a copy/pasteable version of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited my initial post! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that should work.

```
## generate some sample data
set.seed(42)
MAT = matrix(data = runif(26^2) < 0.25, nrow = 26, dimnames = list(LETTERS, LETTERS))

## convert to long format
long = reshape2::melt(MAT, as.is = TRUE)
## filter down to TRUE values  
## and where the first index is lower to deduplicate the symmetry
long = long[long$value & long$Var1 <= long$Var2, ]
long
#     Var1 Var2 value
# 55     C    C  TRUE
# 80     B    D  TRUE
# 82     D    D  TRUE
# 157    A    G  TRUE
# 158    B    G  TRUE
# 159    C    G  TRUE
# 189    G    H  TRUE
# 214    F    I  TRUE
# 237    C    J  TRUE
# ...
```

Comment: >Gregor

It worked for my actual data set! I appreciate your help:)